# Perl Tk code to move mouse from one location to another without user intervention

Tags: perl, pointers, mouse, move, tk-toolkit

I am obviously a mere novice and could use a bit of help.
I am attempting to write a bit of linux perl TK code to create box and:
1) move the mouse pointer to point A............
2) sleep for 2 seconds..........
3) move the mouse pointer to point B...........

*WITHOUT* user intervention.
...I want the mouse pointer to move by itself without having to press 
a button or anything else.
I have heard that this is called warping but i don't know how to write that code.

I have a bit of code here that moves the pmouse pointer....but
it involves a button.........i don't want the button part.
but i don't know how to write the code otherwise.
Besides, i took part of this code from somewhere else
and i don't know how to fix it like i described in the steps above.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Tk;

$count=0;
$m=Tk::MainWindow->new();

# create a button with a callback to do_warp
$button=$m->Button(-text => "Press Me", -command => \&do_warp);

# some filler labels so that the pointer warp is obvious
$filler1=$m->Label(-text => "           ");
$filler2=$m->Label(-text => "           ");

# this label is where the mouse pointer ends up
$l=$m->Label(-text => "Mouse ends up here");

$button->pack();
$filler1->pack();
$filler2->pack();
$l->pack();

#$m->repeat(2 => \&do_warp);

MainLoop;

sub do_warp
  {
  $count++;
  printf("COUNT=|%d|\n", $count);

  if ($count == 1)
    {
    sleep 2;
    $l->eventGenerate('<ButtonPress>',-warp => 1, -x => 10, -y => -10);
    }
  else
    {
    $count = 0;
    sleep 2;
    $l->eventGenerate('<ButtonPress>',-warp => 1, -x => 30, -y => -30);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The button that you press in this code (`$button`) is just a way to cause the function `do_warp` to run.  Write your own version of `do_warp` so that it moves the cursor where you want it, but then call `do_warp` from the main Tk section, without any button.  Looks like you already tried doing that in that `repeat` loop?

My Tk is wicked rusty so I can't help with the exact syntax, but you should be able to do this in the main section without needing a button press to call `do_warp`.